# Does magento 2 have built in timing component like symfony stopwatch?

Tags: magento2, console

Does magento 2 have a built in timer component like Symfony Stopwatch?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html

Would be useful for console commands / cron tasks.

I'm aware that I can load things in but wondered if something already exists and I try not to reinvent the wheel.

I've had a quick scan of the codebase and can't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Symfony stopwatch

My console code looks a bit like this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Stopwatch

```php
    $output->writeln('<info>Start</info>');

    $stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    $stopwatch->start('stopwatch');

    // lengthy process

    $event = $stopwatch->stop('stopwatch');
    $output->writeln((string) $event);
    $output->writeln((string) __("Start : %1", date("d-m-Y H:i:s", (int) ($event->getOrigin() / 1000))));
    $output->writeln((string) __("End : %1", date("d-m-Y H:i:s", (int) (($event->getOrigin() + $event->getEndTime()) / 1000))));
    $output->writeln((string) __("Memory : %1 MiB", $event->getMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
    $output->writeln('<info>Finish</info>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

See `\Magento\Framework\Profiler` and `\Magento\Framework\Profiler\Driver\Standard\Stat` classes

Comment: Seems logical. Does raise a couple of questions. Do you have to have profiler enabled and if not have you got a basic usage example if for example I were to use it within a console script?